# Compilation error Qt Creator with OpenCV libraries(ubuntu)

Tags: qt, opencv, ubuntu, compiler-errors

I was trying to setup Qt IDE with some libraries from OpenCV which i built from source with cmake. I am not quite sure if it is because of the way i include my path or what but i got this compilation error, even after changing my path several times. I am using GCC arm 64bit compiler, Qt 5.9.5, opencv 4.4.0

```
g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../test -I. -isystem /usr/local/include -isystem /usr/local/include -isystem /usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o ../test/main.cpp
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/videoio.hpp:46,
                 from ../test/main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:52:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:359: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
11:24:40: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project test (kit: Desktop)
When executing step "Make"
```

This is my .pro file path

```
INCLUDEPATH+= /usr/local/include
LIBS+= -L"/usr/local/lib"
LIBS += -lopencv_calib3d
LIBS += -lopencv_core
LIBS += -lopencv_features2d
LIBS += -lopencv_flann
LIBS += -lopencv_highgui
LIBS += -lopencv_imgcodecs
LIBS += -lopencv_imgproc
LIBS += -lopencv_ml
LIBS += -lopencv_objdetect
LIBS += -lopencv_photo
LIBS += -lopencv_shape
LIBS += -lopencv_stitching
LIBS += -lopencv_superres
LIBS += -lopencv_video
LIBS += -lopencv_videoio
LIBS += -lopencv_videostab
```

UPDATE***
I have changed my .pro file to be as such

```
INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/local/include/opencv4
LIBS+='pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4'
```

Because the compiler cannot find opencv_modules.hpp, i had to copy it over directly from the build file into my /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2 folder. Next i had a func() out of scope error which i had to solve by doing a `#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"`  instead of manually adding the header files.

Right now my new compilation error is `error: pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4: No such file or directory`

FINAL UPDATE*****
The problem is in `LIBS+='pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4'`, it is not supposed to be ' but `. Now everything works fine. All thanks to Yunus Temurlenk for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps you should check and follow:

1. Be sure you correctly installed fundamental operating system libraries before installing opencv which are mainly described in [here step2](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-ubuntu-18-04/).
2. Also do NOT forget to enable the flag `-D WITH_QT=ON` during cmake.
3. I see that you installed opencv to `usr/local` which is suggested way. After installing opencv, check the version by the command on terminal:

   `pkg-config --modversion opencv4` (or just opencv up to how you configured)

Be sure this output works fine.

4. The correct way to link libraries to Qt:

> ```
> INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv4
> LIBS += `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
> ```

Comment: I have already done steps 1 & 2. pkg-config --modversion opencv4 did not work. So i rebuilt with cmake flag for config to be on. After which the version number works fine. Following that, i used the paths you provided and tried building. However, i am still faced with similar problems

Comment: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../test -I. -isystem /usr/local/include/opencv4 -isystem /usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o ../test/main.cpp
../test/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
../test/main.cpp:31:5: error: ‘imshow’ was not declared in this scope
     imshow( "Frame", frame );
     ^~~~~~

Comment: ../test/main.cpp:34:18: error: ‘waitKey’ was not declared in this scope
     char c=(char)waitKey(25);
                  ^~~~~~~
../test/main.cpp:43:3: error: ‘destroyAllWindows’ was not declared in this scope
   destroyAllWindows();
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Makefile:359: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
14:24:34: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project test (kit: Desktop)
When executing step "Make"

Comment: So you properly did: 1>`cmake` 2> `make` 3> `make install` without any error?

Comment: Yes. Oh i could not run sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main" properly(from step 1) as they said there were some old files existing or something. But i didn't think it would matter that much.

Comment: To eliminate the declaration scope error, i just had to do a ```#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp".``` If i had just done it individually ie ```#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp" ```, i would have this scope error. But now a new problem has popped up during compilation. ```error: pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4: No such file or directory```

Comment: Did you add to cmake: `-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \ ` try also `pkg-config --modversion opencv` command on terminal

Comment: Yes i added that to cmake. The command does not work. I have to do ```pkg-config --modversion opencv4``` for it to work

Comment: Lastly did you run `sudo ldconfig` ?

Comment: Yeah i ran ```sudo ldconfig```. I am not quite sure what to do right now, been stuck at this for a long time . ```sudo find -name pkgconfig
find: ‘./run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
./snap/core18/1888/usr/share/pkgconfig
./snap/gnome-3-28-1804/130/usr/share/pkgconfig
./usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
./usr/local/pkgconfig
./usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/pkgconfig
./usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
./usr/lib/pkgconfig
./usr/share/pkgconfig
```

Comment: 1- `sudo sh -c 'echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf'` then `sudo ldconfig` then `pkg-config --modversion opencv4` should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220196/discussion-between-shane-and-yunus-temurlenk).